# How to remove extra content in table cell using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping two-column table that has extra information in the second column.

```
state    | count  | pct
Florida  | 1 (1)  | 0.5
Colorado | 10 (<1)| 1.0
```

When I run my script, I usually get a variation of:

```
1 \xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0(<1)
```

or

```
10 \xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0(10)
```

for the second cell.

I'm only interested in the first number so the output in BeautifulSoup looks like:

```
 [[u'Florida', u'1'], [u'Colorado', u'10']]
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Can you just split the string and get the first part?

Comment: You are correct. `.split()` worked for this situation. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have `rows`:

```
>>> rows = [
...     [u'Florida', u'1 \xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0(1)'],
...     [u'Colorado', u'10 \xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0(<1)']
... ]
```

Split `count`s and get the first part:

```
>>> rows = [[state, count.split()[0]] for state, count in rows]
>>> rows
[[u'Florida', u'1'], [u'Colorado', u'10']]
```

Comment: Using `.split()` definitely helped with what I needed. Thank you!